# subjqgrid, which event is declenched after edit cell in the subgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using subgrid as a jqgrid.
Which event is declenched after editing a row in the subgrid ? 
I tried `afterSaveCell` but nothing working.

Comment: what you have tried just write code here.Also format your question.

Comment: ok i am so sorry, but really i have spent a lot of time on searching which event is declenched after edit a cell on a subgrid